# Efficient use of Google API-specific service object with Memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

Application is trying to get the list of user's information(>200 Users) using Google Apps Directory API with the help of Service Account.

```
if not memcache.get('directory_service'):
    f = file(KEY_FILE, 'r')
    key = f.read()
    f.close()

    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        service_email,
        key,
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
        sub=GoogleAppAdminEmail)
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

    directory_service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http_auth)
    memcache.set('directory_service', directory_service, 60 * 60 * 2)
else:
    directory_service = memcache.get('directory_service')
user = directory_service.users().get(userKey=username).execute()
```

I thought it would be better to save the `directory_service` object in memcache to reduce the execution time and so that second request onwards application will fetch the object from memcache.

But I got `HttpError 401` after implementing Memcache.

```
File "C:\Users\test\appcode\oauth2client\util.py", line 135, in positional_wrapper

    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\test\appcode\googleapiclient\http.py", line 723, in execute

    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)

HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/username%40mydomain.com?alt=json returned "Login Required">
```

What is the efficient way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

There's little interest in storing the `directory_service` object, because it is created without making calls to external APIs.

What you should store is the `http_auth` object, as this one can be costly to generate.

In addition, tokens from service accounts can only be requested a certain number of times per second. I do not think the exact limit is documented somewhere but if you try to generate too many tokens from the same service account at the same time you will get a `Rate limit exceeded` error.

The good practice is to store the tokens in some shared storage service. It can be memcache or the Datastore. The Google API client comes with [an App Engine specific `StorageByKeyName` class](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#Storage) that you should use. It is backed by the Datastore and uses Memcache as an optional cache layer.

Comment: Even I save the `http_auth` object, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I'll echo what David has said in that storing the auth tokens themselves is much more robust than attempting to store the objects that perform auth flows and make requests. A worst-case for your use-pattern (which you may actually be hitting) is that the token inside the pickled object will expire, leading to auth errors, but with your app still thinking that it can safely grab the object, and hence no need to generate a new one. You may want to store the time until the token expires along with the object, and that may prevent the issue, if that's indeed what's occurring.